# Get next sibling from html source using PHP and xpath

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I am getting a "Trying to get property of non-object" error when using the following code to get the next div id sibling (the div id sibling after 'div id = "XXX"'.  Could someone please tell me how to correct it?  Thanks

```
$Html ='<div id="currency">
    <a href="http://www.link.com/313">
        <div class="sub_item">
          <h3>Sub Categ A</h3>
        </div>
    </a> 
   </div>
   <div id="Next-Sibling">
    <a href="http://www.link.com/111">
        <div class="sub_item">
          <h3>Sub Categ A</h3>
        </div>
    </a> 
   </div>'

function GetNextSibling(){
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($Html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$els = $xpath->query('.//div[@id="currency"]/following-sibling::div[1]/@id');
print_r ($els[0]->nodeValue); //Wanting result "Next-Sibling"
}
```

Comment: Show HTML sample for the same

Comment: For php7 I getting the desire result: https://3v4l.org/Y27Gn. Which php version you using?

Comment: For some reason I am getting a "Trying to get property of non-object" error'  The only difference is from the function, I am returning ($els[0]->nodeValue) - $R = ($els[0]->nodeValue);  return $R;